# Resolution and Browser Compatibility

Tags: html, css, browser, resolution

I am currently designing a basic website however, after nearly completing my CSS I found that when I opened the webpage on a different computer it looked different and not only that it looked different in different ways depending on the web browser.

Therefore I am unsure whether or not it is a problem with browser or resolution compatibility so my question would be can anyone tell me in which field the problem lies (may be both) and maybe advice on the direction I can go to solve the problem.

The following is a link to an online album of screenshots of the webpage run on the four 'main' browsers on my laptop with a resolution of 1600x900 and the family computer with a resolution of 1440x900. Also if the page is resized or zoomed in then things start moving about.

http://postimg.org/gallery/908tlytw/

Thank you in advance for any help or advice, if you want me to provide any further information please just say what you would like to see.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso10646"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-GB"/>
    <meta name="author" content="###########"/>
    <meta name="designer" content="##########"/>
    <meta name="description" content="The official website of ##########, promoting her humanist services."/>
    <!--<meta name="keywords" content="##########, humanist"/>-->
    <meta name="language" content="english"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet lego.css"/>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div class="toparea">
            <img src="Client's Logo.png" id="logo"/>
            <h1 id="title">Significant Ceremonies by ##########</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Tel: ############</li>
                <li>E-mail: #######################</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sidearea">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Humanism</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Specialist Areas</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="mainarea">
            <h2 id="subtitle">Home</h2>
            <p>"I would rather live a life based on honesty, compassion and humanity through my own free will instead of it coming from the fear of
                divine beings." - ###########</p>
            <p>Welcome to my web site, here you can find information about the services I perform and about Humanism itself. Please feel free to 
                navigate around my site and if you have any questions you can either contact me directly or use the form on the 'Contact Me' page.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bottomarea">
            <ul>
                <li>Tel: ############</li>
                <li>E-mail: #######################</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="BHA logo.jpg" id="bhalogo"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#page
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #E6F5E6;
    font-family: vijaya, sakkal majalla, narkisim, monotype corsiva, jasmineupc, gabriola, french script mt, footlight mt light, calisto mt, papyrus;
}

.toparea
{
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#logo
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#title
{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #002E00;
}

.toparea ul
{
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 40px;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidearea
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.sidearea ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.sidearea ul li
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #4DB84D;
    border-color: #002E00;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.sidearea ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#subtitle
{
    color: #002E00;
}

.mainarea
{
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /*background-color: #EEF8EE;*/
}

.bottomarea
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.bottomarea ul
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 360px;
    width: 610px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#bhalogo
{
    position: fixed;
    right: 388px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your image link doesn't work?

Comment: I can also see your `src` and `href` references are potentially incorrect. For instance the stylesheet reference should be, as an example `href="lego.css"` depending on the file location. (similar issue with the images).

Comment: Sounds like you need to investigate [Responsive design](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+design) and [CSS media queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS+media+queries).

Comment: @YaMo I will get the image link sorted when I'm next on a computer, the src and href are all working fine I just name files awfully.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for your advice I'll start looking into them.

Comment: Where did you get the `charset=iso10646` from? While it is a character set, it does not designate an _encoding_. Specify the encoding, e.g. `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`.

Comment: Anyway, one difference I can see is where a computer doesn't have any of the fonts you specify, then they display the browsers' default fonts. If browser interoperability is that important, include some well-known font names at the end that have a high probability if being present.

Comment: @Mr Lister I was unsure which encoding label to use and I read somewhere to just put charset=iso10646, thanks for showing me that mistake.

Comment: @YaMo The image link should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that you set `left: 25%` and `width: 800px`.  You're getting exactly what you asked for.  The left side of that div is 25% across the page, and the width of it is 800 pixels wide.  While this may work for a specific resolution, it will certainly look off-center to others.

Leave your width set and set `margin: 0 auto`;  This sets an `auto` margin for left/right, which will effectively center your div on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when I tried your suggestion and got rid of the left: 25% it caused the page to have a text-align to the left and not be centred.

Comment: @Spudious, `left` has nothing to do with text align.  You have something else wrong in your CSS.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean text-align. The whole page div shifts to the left.